# map json object with dynamic key to java object

Tags: java, json

how do i map the below json to a java class, where the key is dynamic

```
{
    "steps":
    {
        "1":{
                a:"a",
                b:"b",
                c:"c"
            },
        "2":{ 
                a:"a",
                b:"b",
                c:"c"
            },
        "3":{ 
                a:"a",
                b:"b",
                c:"c"
            }
    }
}
```

Normally, if the json object is of this kind, it is easy to map to an object.

```
{
    "steps":
    [
        {
            a:"a",
            b:"b",
            c:"c"
        },
        {
            a:"a",
            b:"b",
            c:"c"
        },
        {
            a:"a",
            b:"b",
            c:"c"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the class for this will be:

```
public class Example
{
    private Steps[] steps;

}

public class Steps
{
    private String b;

    private String c;

    private String a;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824674/how-to-convert-json-objects-with-number-as-field-key-in-java

Comment: Use map for steps instead of array.

Comment: Thanks using `Map` works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case someone else come looking for same/similar problem. A `Map` should be used in case the keys are dynamic. In this case, `Example` class would look something like:

```
public class Example
{
    private Map<String, Steps> steps;

}
```

In `HashMap`, keys insertion order is not preserved, therefore `LinkedHashMap` should be used if insertion order of keys matter.