# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Hi I am try to parse some JSON by GSON which used number as the key.
I reference the post but it give some error and I don't know why.

[How to convert json objects with number as field key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824674/how-to-convert-json-objects-with-number-as-field-key-in-java)

I also see the post but still cannot solve my problem.

["Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

[image]

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = gson.fromJson("./src/main/resources/input.json", type);

    }
}
```

The json file is

```
{
  "1":{"id":"1"}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON as well?

Comment: Ok, I have posted the file as well,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fromJson` method doesn't receive a filename, it receives an actual JSON: [look at the docs here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)

But there is an [overload](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.reflect.Type-) that receives a Reader instead:

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("./src/main/resources/input.json"))
{
    map = gson.fromJson(reader, type)
}
catch (...) { ... }
```